# Onclick is triggered twice after changing the value manually in jquery

Tags: event-bubbling

I have changed the onclick(for li element) using the inspect element. In onClick I have called a function it was invoked twice.

Here is my sample code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function a(val)
{
alert(val);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li onClick="a(1)"> 1 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have expanded the answer with a workaround/solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Google Chrome. This is a bug/problem with the Inspect Element feature.

If you use Inspect Element to change or remove the `onclick` handler of an element, it doesn't work as expected. The new Javascript code is **ADDED** as a new handler to the existing list of the `onclick` handlers, rather than replacing the existing handler of the old code.

This is incorrect and a bug, because Inspect Element allows user to replace the code, and it looks like it's replaced - *but hidden from the user, it's actually appended as a new handler* - so the result is not what it would seem like.

If the code or the `onclick` attribute is deleted, the JS code is still executed as it remains registered as a handler.

This is highly misleading and makes the Inspect Element *nearly useless* for debugging event handler JS bugs.

To try it out:

1. Right-click any element and click *Inspect element* (or *Inspect*).
2. Add or modify its `onclick` handler to `alert('stack');`.
3. Again, modify the `onclick` handler to `alert('overflow');`.
4. Now, click the element to fire the handler.

You may think that you will just get one alert with the word `overflow`. But you will actually get two alerts, one with `stack` and another with `overflow`. This means the code `alert('stack');` is still in the handler, even though it's not visible on the DOM tree.

*There is no permanent fix for this problem. The following workarounds may help. Reporting it to Google may encourage them to fix it in a future version of the browser.*

## Workarounds

- Use Mozilla Firefox. The behavior of Inspect Element in Firefox is as expected - the browser really replaces the old handler instead of adding a new handler to the list.
- If you need to use Google Chrome, do the following:

  1. With the element selected in the *Developer Tools* window's *Elements* tab, click the *Event Listeners* tab (this is on the other pane which may appear below or on the right side).
  2. Make sure that the *Ancestors* checkbox is **unchecked**.
  3. If your element already has an `onclick` handler, you should be able to see a `click` event handler listed. If you don't see anything, try clicking *Refresh* button (next to *Ancestors* checkbox).

     - If you still don't see it, close the *Developer Tools* and right-click the element in the page and click *Inspect* to open it again.
  4. Click the rightward arrow next to the `click` event handler. It will open and you will get a list of all the registered handlers (listed with the `tag#id.class` notation).
     [image: Screenshot of Developer Tools showing the click handler list with Remove button]
  5. In the DOM tree (top pane or left pane), double-click and edit the `onclick` handler code and confirm it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  6. In the *Event Listeners* tab, click *Refresh* button again. You will see that a new handler has been added.
  7. Hover over the handlers and you will see a *Remove* button appearing on each of them. Click this button on each handler until **only one** remains.

     - The order doesn't matter - you can start at the bottom, the top or even go randomly - internally, the *Remove* button removes handlers in the order they were added.
     - If there's only one handler left, you can be sure that's your latest code - it doesn't matter which handler was left.
  8. To change the `onclick` code again, repeat steps 5 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

I notice this bug as well. While working on my project this week with ajax calls.

Having a button like this:

```
<button id="mybutton" type="button" onclick="sendMessage('12345')"></button>
```

If you go into the inspector and edit '12345' to 'abcde'. Then clicking the button will cause the button to fire twice. Once as '12345' and once as 'abcde'.

To solve the double sending you can attach the event listener with an ID rather than using html's onclick. So instead use something like:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    sendMessage('12345');
});
```

This will not suffer the same double sending bug.

However, anything you edit on the inspector will not do anything now, it will be disregarded.